# OpenGL: drawing a cube

Tags: c++, opengl

I just started to learn about OpenGL and this is my first program to draw a cube. I'm quite lost here as I was able to draw a rectangle by specifying coordinates for the rectangle in 2d, but I can't draw the cube by specifying coordinates in (x, y, z) format. What am I missing here?

Here is the code:

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

// Open an OpenGL window
GLFWwindow* window;

/****Step 1: define vertices in (x, y, z) form****/

// Coordinates to draw a cube
const GLdouble coordinates[8][3] = {
    {-0.5, -0.5, -0.5},
    {0.5, -0.5, -0.5},
    {0.5, -0.5, 0.5},
    {-0.5, -0.5, 0.5},
    {-0.5, 0.5, 0.5},
    {-0.5, 0.5, -0.5},
    {0.5, 0.5, -0.5},
    {0.5, 0.5, 0.5}
};
/************************/


int main( void ) {
    if (!glfwInit()){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW.\n");
        return -1;
    }

    // Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context
    window = glfwCreateWindow(700, 500, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (window == NULL) {
            fprintf(stderr, "glfw failed to create window.\n");
            //glfwTerminate();
            return -1;
            }
    // Make the window's context current
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    glewInit();
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK){
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW: %s.\n", glewGetErrorString(glewInit()));
        return -1;
    }
    // 4x anti aliasing
    glfwWindowHint(GLFW_SAMPLES, 4);

    int cube_size = sizeof(coordinates)/sizeof(coordinates[0]);
    /**Step 2: send this cube vertices to OpenGL through a buffer**/
    GLuint vertexBuffer; // Declare vertex buffer
    glGenBuffers(1, &vertexBuffer); // generating 1 buffer, put resulting identifier in this buffer
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_size*12, coordinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    /************************/

    std::cout << sizeof(coordinates)/sizeof(coordinates[0]);

    /**Step 3: Main loop for OpenGL draw the shape**
    /* Main loop */
    do{
        glClearColor(1.0, 0.1, 0.1, .0);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
        glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexBuffer);
        glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
        glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP, 0, cube_size);
        glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

        // Swap front and back rendering buffers
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        //Poll for and process events
        glfwPollEvents();
    } // check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
    while(glfwGetKey(window, GLFW_KEY_ESCAPE) != GLFW_PRESS && glfwWindowShouldClose(window) == 0);
    /***********************************************/


    // Close window and terminate GLFW
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    // Exit program
    exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
}
```

Comment: Where is the issue ? Which line ?

Comment: Note that calls to glfwWindowHint() do not affect open windows, they only affect windows opened with subsequent calls to glfwCreateWindow().
see: 
http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga4fd9e504bb937e79588a0ffdca9f620b

Comment: what is actually rendered ? what gfx HW is used on what OS? have you tried changing clear color from black to something else? (if textures enabled with no texture bound the result color is often black) have you moved the object and camera to both sides of Z axis? (perspective matrices often view in negative Z axis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a type mismatch in your program. In this declaration:

```
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, (void*)0);
```

you are saying to OpenGL to interpret your data as float, but your coordinates points are declared double.

I suggest you to change GLdouble to GLfloat at coordinate type declaration.

By the way, with those points you will not get a cube, but only a partial sketch of it

Comment: i think because the Z direction points towards the screen so all i can expect to see is a square. But the code above doesn't draw a square either after I change from glfloat to gldouble. can u explain why this happens?

Comment: Because here: `glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, cube_size*12, coordinates, GL_STATIC_DRAW);` you made an assumption that 12 is 3*4, where 4 is the lenght of a type. Change `cube_size*12` by sizeof(coordinates) and it will works

Answer (score 1):

In addition to other answers ... well there can be more options what is wrong

1. **wrong matrices**

   You have to be looking at the object actually so you need pointing Z axis of camera towards the object (+Z or -Z ... depends on projection used). If you use perspective then your object must be inside `<Znear,Zfar>` range
2. **You are passing 8 points of cube**

   That is not enough as cube has 6 sides each with 4 lines ... that is bit more points to pass in this way. If you got a decent **OpenGL** driver then you can use indices (element array) but then you should use only `GLuint` and `Quads` for element array ... because some gfx drivers had problems with odd points primitives and different data types (especially **ATI** in the past...). If you got **nVidia** then you should be fine but to avoid future compatibility problems later ...
3. **something left enabled/disabled**

   enabled textures usually draws all in black, cull face can skip if mesh is not OK or camera is inside ... Also check `glDepthFunc` and viewing Z direction (or try disable `GL_DEPTH_TEST`)
4. **shader**

   You are using **VBO/VAO** but no shader in your code what so ever. If you do not want to use shaders then for **nVidia** compatible HW use [default layout locations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20574219/2521214) **(but that is dirty incompatible trick and should not be used for public Apps...)**. Use `glVertexPointer,glColorPointer,...` instead or write easy shader emulating fixed functionality of what you need supported.

mine C++ example:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- Open GL VAO example ------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#ifndef _OpenGL_VAO_example_h
#define _OpenGL_VAO_example_h
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
GLuint vbo[4]={-1,-1,-1,-1};
GLuint vao[4]={-1,-1,-1,-1};
const GLfloat vao_pos[]=
    {
//  x    y    z
    -1.0,-1.0,-1.0,
    +1.0,-1.0,-1.0,
    +1.0,+1.0,-1.0,
    -1.0,+1.0,-1.0,
    -1.0,-1.0,+1.0,
    +1.0,-1.0,+1.0,
    +1.0,+1.0,+1.0,
    -1.0,+1.0,+1.0,
    };

const GLfloat vao_col[]=
    {
//  r   g   b
    0.0,0.0,0.0,
    1.0,0.0,0.0,
    1.0,1.0,0.0,
    0.0,1.0,0.0,
    0.0,0.0,1.0,
    1.0,0.0,1.0,
    1.0,1.0,1.0,
    0.0,1.0,1.0,
    };

const GLuint vao_ix[]=
    {
    0,1,2,3,
    4,5,6,7,
    0,1,5,4,
    1,2,6,5,
    2,3,7,6,
    3,0,4,7,
    };
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void vao_init()
    {
    GLuint i;
    glGenVertexArrays(4,vao);
    glGenBuffers(4,vbo);
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
    i=0; // vertex
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vao_pos),vao_pos,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(i,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
    i=1; // indices
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vao_ix),vao_ix,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(i,4,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,GL_FALSE,0,0);
    i=2; // normal
    i=3; // color
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,vbo[i]);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sizeof(vao_col),vao_col,GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(i);
    glVertexAttribPointer(i,3,GL_FLOAT,GL_FALSE,0,0);

    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER,0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(1);
//  glDisableVertexAttribArray(2);
    glDisableVertexAttribArray(3);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void vao_exit()
    {
    glDeleteVertexArrays(4,vao);
    glDeleteBuffers(4,vbo);
    }
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
void vao_draw()
    {
    glBindVertexArray(vao[0]);
//  glDrawArrays(GL_LINE_LOOP,0,8);                 // lines ... no indices
    glDrawElements(GL_QUADS,24,GL_UNSIGNED_INT,0);  // indices (choose just one line not both !!!)
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//--- end. ---------------------------------------------------------------------
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This is how it looks like:

[image: example]

- left side is painted with `glDrawArrays`
- right side is painted with `glDrawElements`
- call `vao_init()` after GL initialization (extensions included)
- call `vao_exit()` before GL destruction
- call `vao_draw()` inside draw loop

Mine matrices are like this:

```
glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
glLoadIdentity();
gluPerspective(60,float(scr.xs)/float(scr.ys),0.1,100.0);
glMatrixMode(GL_TEXTURE);
glLoadIdentity();
glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
glLoadIdentity();
glTranslatef(0.0,0.0,-10.0);
```

where:

- `scr.xs,scr.ys` is the GL window resolution
- `modelview` is rotating in timer to animate the cube ...
- `znear=0.1` , `zfar=100.0`, **FOV** angle is 60 degrees
- cube is 10 units before focus point so 9.9 units before `znear` camera projection plane
- cube size is 2 units (+/-1.0) so it fits inside frustrum ...

Draw call is like this:

```
glDisable(GL_CULL_FACE);
glDisable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
vao_draw();
```

**[Notes]**

In example the faces are not with strict polygon winding so do not enable `CULL_FACE` !!! Also the texture disabling is necessary (in mine App) due to leftover from mine GL engine ... **This is just dirty no shader present example** so I used **nVidia's default layout positions** so on different HW you need the shader also ... see bullet **#4**

Comment: thank you very much!! This gives me a really nice explanation!!

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your camera is located inside the box so the face gets culled. Try pushing the box to a more distant z position.

Comment: can you give me some more details please? i'm using GL_PROJECTION but I don't think I'm on right track cos I see nothing changed ... Sorry i'm pretty new ..

Comment: Cull process is disabled by default

Comment: I think he meant "clipped"