# Show #include hierarchy in C++Builder

Tags: c++, include, c++builder, c++builder-2007

I'm having trouble with someone else's code, what seems to be header files included out of order.  (E.g., I'm getting redefinition errors, some of which are even in the same file!)  It would be useful to see the #include tree the C++Builder compiler is using, similar to Visual Studio's -showIncludes flag.  Is there any such functionality; if so, how do I access it?  I am specifically using C++Builder 2007.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sadly, there are no Borland C Compiler options for displaying the hierarchy of `#include`d files.  See Embarcadero's [BCC32 CLI docs](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/devwin32/bcc32_xml.html).

However, an alternative (granted, not as clean) is to use the [Borland C Compiler Preprocessor](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/radstudio2007/RS2007_helpupdates/HUpdate4/EN/html/devwin32/cpp32_xml.html), e.g.

```
CPP32 -Sr source.cpp # outputs source.i with comments and indentation retained
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually happens if you including multiple times files which contains global constants, variables and sometimes even `#defines`. This is very common for **MDI** apps where the master `Form` contains include of the child `Form`s and some of them use the same libs ...

The include hierarchy would not help for this unless you are planning to edit all source files `#include` order which can lead to problems later on (especially compatibility)...

To remedy this you should encapsulate all such files with

```
#ifndef _file_name_h
#define _file_name_h
// here your source and includes
#endif
```

statements. Like in this example:

- [OpenGL drawing a cube](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28737958/2521214)

That will prevent multiple definitions and compilations on pre-compiler level as the source will be processed only the first time (while `#define _file_name_h` is still not defined).