# Rendering in opengl 3.1+ without VBO

Tags: c++, opengl

I want to know if its possible to draw in opengl 3.1+ core profile using vertex arrays ( client side rendering) without using the VBO and VAO. I know in opengl 3.1+ core profile use of VAO is essential while using VAO. I want to know if its possible to draw without using VBO and VAO by using vertex arrays (client side rendering). If not possible (which I think is true), can you please provide some reference document as well.

Comment: Comments here may help  : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31326918/opengl-3-0-drawing-a-triangle-without-vbos-or-vaos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer: no**

Immediate Mode is deprecated with OpenGL >= 3.0, although some implemetations still contain parts of the fixed-functionality pipeline.

OpenGL 3.1 removes most of the functions of `Immediate Mode`

See [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL)

In order to draw something in Core Profile in OpenGL 3.1 or higher you have to use at least one VBO and VAO

Comment: I am talking about using the vertex array (client side rendering) without creating VBO and VAO not immediate mode. I think these 2 are different though even I feel they both have been deprecated. not sure though

Comment: One note: It *is* technically possible to draw without a VBO --- by [using gl_VertexID](https://rauwendaal.net/2014/06/14/rendering-a-screen-covering-triangle-in-opengl/). Note that this is really only appropriate for simple things (e.g. full-screen triangles).

Comment: @PankajBansal "Client-side rendering", as you call it, is just the driver doing the `glGenBuffers` / `glBuffer[Sub]Data` for you, instead of you doing it manually. It still has to be uploaded to the GPU, so doing `glBuffer[Sub]Data` before drawing a buffer will accomplish the same (but faster, as the application knows better how to deal with buffers than a driver that has to do guesswork!).