# How do I mix a normal map into a reflection of a skybox?

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

Im triying to create a water example and I know that the first thig requiered is to be able to make a reflection, that is done.

I'm stuck in the next step which is to combine the reflection with a normal map.

What I tried was to load the cube texture as I normally would, calculate the reflection and then load the normal map and combine them in the final step, but the water disappears.

Here's my code:

**Vertex Shader**

```
attribute vec3 a_normBT;
attribute vec3 a_normL;
attribute vec3  a_normTan;
attribute vec3 a_posL;
attribute vec2 a_uv;
uniform mat4 u_W;
uniform mat4 u_WVP;
varying vec3 v_normW;
varying vec3 v_normBT;
varying vec3 v_normTan;
varying vec3 v_posW;
varying vec2 v_uv;
void main()
{
    gl_Position  = u_WVP * vec4(a_posL, 1.0);
    v_uv = a_uv;
    v_normW = normalize((u_W*vec4(a_normL, 0.0)).xyz);
    v_normBT = normalize((u_W*vec4(a_normBT,0.0)).xyz);
    v_normTan = normalize((u_W*vec4(a_normTan,0.0)).xyz);
    v_posW = (u_W*vec4(a_posL, 1.0)).xyz;
}
```

**Fragment shader**

```
precision mediump float;
uniform samplerCube u_s_texture;
uniform sampler2D u_s_normalMap;
uniform vec3 u_cpos;// the camera position is already in world space
varying vec3 v_normW;
varying vec3 v_normBT;
varying vec3 v_normTan;
varying vec3 v_posW;
varying vec2 v_uv;
void main()
{
    vec4 tempText =  texture2D(u_s_normalMap, v_uv);
    vec3 Normal = normalize(v_normW);
    vec3 totalDifusse = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    vec3 totalSpecular = vec3(0.0,0.0,0.0);
    vec3 toEye = u_cpos- v_posW;
    vec3 reflectDir = reflect(normalize(-toEye), normalize(v_normW));  // reflect() in non linear
    gl_FragColor = tempText*textureCube(u_s_texture,reflectDir);
}
```

What I expect to happen is that the quad I have should have static ripples.
Thank you.

Comment: What do you see if you do `gl_FragColor= tempText`? Maybe temText.a is equal to 0. Anyway what you probably want to do is take `tempText`, use it's value to change `v_normW` and then reflect it.

Comment: When I use tempText iI see my normal map

Answer (score 0):

Do not know the coordinate system setup of your system and therefore uniforms exact meaning and too lazy to analyze/debug unknown code to help you.

Instead look at this: [Normal mapping gone horribly wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28541305/2521214)

- which is very similar to your task
- The main idea is to compute the fragments normal vector in [GCS] global (world coordinate) system
- and use that as 3D cubemap texture coordinate where your environment skybox texture is holding...
- This is not physically correct (unless surface is fluorescent) but is easy enough as start point and looks good
- when done then compute vector from fragment to camera in [GCS]
- then compute its reflection around computed normal
- and use that as 3D cubemap texture coordinate

Also have you check `glGetShaderInfoLog` ?

- very often a small syntax error prevent GLSL linkage using fixed function instead shader and if you have not [compatible written layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20574219/2521214) then you see nothing rendered or black ...
- see [simple compelte GL+GLSL+VAO/VBO example in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31913542/2521214) how the `glGetShaderInfoLog` is used.