# Which OpenGL Primitive should I use for draw an triangulation?

Tags: python, opengl, triangulation

I've the following image :

[image]

That I was able to triangulate like the following : 
[image]

I did it using the [triangle](https://pypi.org/project/triangle/) library of python. My triangulation result is stored into a `dict` object which look like that:

```
>>> triangulation["vertices"]
array([[ 23.        , 282.        ],
       [ 24.        , 254.        ],
       [ 30.        , 239.        ],
       [ 43.        , 219.        ],
       [ 60.        , 204.        ], ...  And so on ...



>>> triangulation["triangles"]
array([[ 89, 106, 105],
       [ 99,  35,  86],
       [110,  68,  87],
       [ 47,  66,  83],
       [ 72,  82,  74], ...  And so on ...
```

Now, I want to distord and draw this texture as a mesh using OpenGL. I was wondering which primitive should I use? I think that `TRIANGLE_STRIP` is the right solution but it's a complex triangulation and it seems obvious that only one TRIANGLE_STRIP will not be enough.

Comment: What's wrong with `TRIANGLES`?

Comment: my triangles need to be connected, no ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've 2 arrays. The first array contains the 2 dimensional vertex coordinates and the second array contains the indices.
You have to use [`glDrawElements`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawElements.xhtml) tor draw the triangle primitives which are contained in the 2nd array. The indices refer to the corresponding vertex coordinates of the 1st array.

First you've to create a floating point buffer for the vertex coordinates and an integral buffer for the indices. The easiest way is to use [NumPy](http://www.numpy.org/), to transform nested list or arrays to array buffers.

Assuming that you've an array of `vertices` in the form *[[x0, y0], [x1, y1], [x2, y2],...]* and an array of `indices` in the form *[[a0, b0, c0], [a1, b1, c1], [a2, b2, c2],...]*, then the buffers can be created like this:

```py
import numpy as np

vertex_array = np.array(vertices, dtype=np.float32)

no_of_indices = len(indices) * 3
index_array = np.array(indices, dtype=np.uint32)
```

The same can be done by using [`ctypes`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), instead of NumPy. But then the lists have to be *flattened* in the form *[x0, y0, x1, y1, x2, y2,...]* respectively *[a0, b0, c0, a1, b1, c1, a2, b2, c2,...]*:

```py
vertex_array = (ctypes.c_float * len(flat_vertices))(*flat_vertices)

no_of_indices = len(flat_indices) * 3
index_array = (ctypes.c_uint32 * no_of_indices)(*flat_indices)
```

Create a vertex array object. See [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification#Vertex_Array_Object):

```py
vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
glBindVertexArray(vao)

ibo = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ibo)
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, index_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

vbo = glGenBuffers(1)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
glBindVertexArray(0)
```

If you want to draw the triangle primitives  it is sufficient to bind the vertex array object and to call `glDrawElements`:

```py
glBindVertexArray(vao)
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, no_of_indices, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, None)
```

---

Regarding to the comment:

> [...] I already know how to texture a plane by using `glTexCoord2f` then `glVertex3f` but didn't figure out how I can do it with a vao.

The easiest way is to create a separate array of texture coordinates. Assuming you've the texture coordinates `texAttr` in the form [[u0, v0], [u1, v1], [u2, v2],...]. 
Generating the buffer is straight forward:

```py
texAttr_array = np.array(texAttr, dtype=np.float32)
```

If you have a shader program, then you've to add the texture coordinate attribute:

e.g.

```c
layout (location = 0) in vec2 vertex;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 texAttr;
```

and to define an array of generic vertex attribute data.

```py
vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
glBindVertexArray(vao)

# [...] index buffer

vbo = glGenBuffers(2)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0])
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1])
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texAttr_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
glVertexAttribPointer(1, 2, GL_FLOAT, False, 0, None)
glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
glBindVertexArray(0)
```

If you use  compatibility profile and the fixed function attributes, then you've to specify the [`glTexCoordPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoordPointer.xml) and enable the client state [`GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml).
Note, the client state `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY` and [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) is mapped to the vertex attribute 0. See [What are the Attribute locations for fixed function pipeline in OpenGL 4.0++ core profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573235/what-are-the-attribute-locations-for-fixed-function-pipeline-in-opengl-4-0-cor/51949673#51949673):

```py
vao = glGenVertexArrays(1)
glBindVertexArray(vao)

# [...] index buffer

vbo = glGenBuffers(2)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[0])
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW)
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo[1])
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, texAttr_array, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)
glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, None)
glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY)

glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0)
glBindVertexArray(0)
```

Note, if you don't use a shader, then 2 dimensional texturing has to be enabled by

```py
glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
```

---

Regarding to the comment:

> I d'like to displace vertex one by one [...]

A single vertex coordinate can be changed by [`glBufferSubData`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBufferSubData.xhtml), where the 2nd parameter is a byte offset to the vertex coordinate. The offset for the coordinate `i` would be `4*2*i` (4 is the size of float in bytes, and each coordinate consist of 2 components *x* and *y*).

Comment: Thank you, how can this vertex array be textured ? And do you think it will be easy to modify its vertex position in real time ?

Comment: For the texturing you need texture coordinates. See [How do opengl texture coordinates work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5532595/how-do-opengl-texture-coordinates-work). What do you mean by *" modify its vertex position in real time"*? Do you want to displace or rotate the mesh? Do you want to generate distortions?

Comment: I d'like to displace vertex one by one. I already know how to texture a plane by using `glTexCoord2f` then  `glVertex3f` but didn't figure out how I can do it with a vao.

Comment: and I'm still learning and it's damn hard ^^ . Not sure If it should be a vertex or a fragment shader. I'm sure that your answer is correct but I need to make it work before accept it. Good exercice by the way.

Comment: of course, I can't make it work : ) Are you sure about `glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)` after `glTexCoordPointer()` ? it doesn't looks like the example I found here : https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/VBO_-_just_examples where `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` is used instead of `GL_VERTEX_ARRAY`. it perturbs me a bit..

Comment: and about `glTexCoordPointer(2, False, 0, None)`, it is `False` and not `GL_FLOAT` ? not sure about this too

Comment: @snoobdogg Of course it has to be `GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY` respectively `GL_FLOAT`. Further `glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)` is needed

Comment: it wooorkks :  )

Comment: By the way, I had to invert tex coordinates vertically: `texAttr = [[vert[0] / img_width, img_height - vert[1] / img_height] for vert in vertices]` and then `vertex_array[:, 1] = img_height - vertex_array[:, 1]`