# Rendering Image in Pygame Using PyOpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, pygame, pyopengl

I am working on a project for the Computer Science Club at my school and trying to learn Pygame/PyOpenGL at the same time.

Right now i'm just trying to do some basic stuff. I'm trying to render an image in a window using Pygame and PyOpenGL. Here is a [link](https://github.com/LukeJelly/FractalEscape) to my code (I'm not sure if Github Repositories are OK).

Code as requested(It mite be easier to read this on github):

```
import pygame
from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GL import shaders
import unittest
import numpy as np
from ctypes import sizeof, c_float, c_void_p


def renderSplash(image):
       # using resources in open gl generally follows the form of generate, bind, modify

    # Generate: request a buffer for our vertices
    vbo = glGenBuffers(1)

    # Bind: set the newly requested buffer as the active GL_ARRAY_BUFFER. 
    #   All subsequent modifications of GL_ARRAY_BUFFER will affect our vbo
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo)

    # Modify: Tell OpenGL to load data into the buffer. 

    # I've added two more coordinates to each vertex here for determining the position within the texture.
    # These two additional coordinates are typically refered to as uv coordinates.
    # Also there are now two triangles that cover the entire viewport.
    vertex_data = np.array([-1, -1, 0, 0,  -1, 1, 0, 1,  1, 1, 1, 1,  -1, -1, 0, 0,  1, 1, 1, 1,  1, -1, 1, 0], np.float32)
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertex_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW)

    vertex_position_attribute_location = 0
    uv_attribute_location = 1

    # glVertexAttribPointer basically works in the same way as glVertexPointer with two exceptions:
    #   First, it can be used to set the data source for any vertex attributes.
    #   Second, it has an option to normalize the data, which I have set to GL_FALSE.
    glVertexAttribPointer(vertex_position_attribute_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(c_float)*4, c_void_p(0))
    # vertex attributes need to be enabled
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)
    glVertexAttribPointer(uv_attribute_location, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(c_float)*4, c_void_p(sizeof(c_float)*2))
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(1)

    # Generate: request a texture
    image_texture = glGenTextures(1)

    # Bind: set the newly requested texture as the active GL_TEXTURE_2D.
    #   All subsequent modifications of GL_TEXTURE_2D will affect our texture (or how it is used)
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, image_texture)


    width = image.get_width()
    height = image.get_height()

    # retrieve a byte string representation of the image.
    # The 3rd parameter tells pygame to return a vertically flipped image, as the coordinate system used
    # by pygame differs from that used by OpenGL
    image_data = pygame.image.tostring(image, "RGBA", True)

    # Modify: Tell OpenGL to load data into the image
    mip_map_level = 0
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, mip_map_level, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image_data)

    # set the filtering mode for the texture
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)

    vertex_shader = shaders.compileShader("""
        #version 330
        layout(location = 0) in vec2 pos;
        layout(location = 1) in vec2 uvIn;
        out vec2 uv;
        void main() {
            gl_Position = vec4(pos, 0, 1);
            uv = uvIn;
        }
        """, GL_VERTEX_SHADER)

    fragment_shader = shaders.compileShader("""
        #version 330
        out vec4 fragColor;
        in vec2 uv;
        uniform sampler2D tex;
        void main() {
            fragColor = texture(tex, uv);
        }
    """, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER)

    shader_program = shaders.compileProgram(vertex_shader, fragment_shader)


    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)

    # Enable alpha blending
    glEnable(GL_BLEND)
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA)

    glUseProgram(shader_program)

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)

def main():
    pygame.quit()
    pygame.init()
    image = pygame.image.load("Background.jpg")

    width = image.get_width()
    height = image.get_height()
    # width = 1920
    # height = 1080
    size = (width,height)
    pygame.display.set_mode(size, pygame.OPENGL | pygame.DOUBLEBUF | pygame.HWSURFACE)
    glViewport(0, 0, width, height)


    renderSplash(image)
    pygame.display.flip()
    close_window()

def close_window():
    key_pressed = False
    while not key_pressed:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                key_pressed = True

main()
```

My problem is when I run SplashScreen.py on my Desktop (Win10 Pro, 1903, OS Build 18362.86,Python 3.7.2) I get the following 
[image: error]

Output in text format as Requested:

```
                                                      pygame 1.9.6
Hello from the pygame community. https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "SplashScreen.py", line 122, in <module>
    main()
  File "SplashScreen.py", line 111, in main
    renderSplash(image)
  File "SplashScreen.py", line 95, in renderSplash
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 6)
  File "C:\Users\LukeJ\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\OpenGL\platform\baseplatform.py", line 402, in __call__
    return self( *args, **named )
OSError: exception: access violation reading 0x0000000000000000
```

But if I run this code on my Laptop (Win10 Pro, 1903, OS Build 18362.86, Python 3.7.2), it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong in my code? What do I need to do to test for this problem and hopefully fix it in my code?

Comment: Please add your related code and out to question as text. Images and links are not that helpful.

Comment: @KlausD.  Updated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delete

<s>`glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)`</s>

and your code will work.

[`glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glEnableClientState.xml) enables the client-side capability for vertex coordinates, it activates the deprecated fixed function attribute and is related to [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL).
This counteracts with the vertex attribute specification and [`glEnableVertexAttribArray(0)`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glEnableVertexAttribArray.xhtml).
The fixed function vertex coordinates would have to be defined by  [`glVertexPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glVertexPointer.xml) rather than [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml). *"access violation reading 0x0000000000000000"* occurs, because there is no fixed function function vertex data set, but it is enabled.

Comment: That worked! So why would this work on my laptop but not my desktop if they running the same os? Some sort of driver difference? My laptop is running Intel HD and my desktop has a dedicated GPU. Maybe that's it?

Comment: @LukeKelly This depends on the graphic hardware and OpenGL driver. Possibli this is related to [What are the Attribute locations for fixed function pipeline in OpenGL 4.0++ core profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573235/what-are-the-attribute-locations-for-fixed-function-pipeline-in-opengl-4-0-cor/51949673#51949673).