# Texture doesn't get rendered when applying a shader in OpenGL

Tags: c, opengl, glsl, shader, opengl-4

Following a tutorial, I'm trying to render text in OpenGL using FreeType. As such, a grayscale 8-bit image is used as texture for each character in a way that each byte of the image corresponds to the texture's red component.

In order to render the text in other colors, it's suggested that you use a Shader. However, when using the provided shader, instead of seeing a colored letter, I see a colored box, as if there was no texture involved at all.

Here's how it looks like with no Shader:

[image: img]

And here's how it looks with the Shader:

[image: img]

(the box also gets its position shifted)

Here's the Vertex Shader code:

```c
#version 330 core
layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex;
out vec2 TexCoords;
void main() {
    gl_Position = vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoords = vertex.zw;
}
```

Here's the Fragment Shader code:

```c
#version 330 core
in vec2 TexCoords;
out vec4 color;
uniform sampler2D text;
uniform vec4 textColor;
void main() {
    vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);
    color = textColor * sampled;
}
```

And here's the code that renders on the screen:

```c
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
// Shader here
glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
glUniform4f(
    glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "textColor"),
    0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
);

glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "text"), 0);

// Draw here
glBegin(GL_QUADS);
glTexCoord2f(1., 0.);
glVertex2f(20. / WIDTH, 20. / HEIGHT);

glTexCoord2f(0., 0.);
glVertex2f(100. / WIDTH, 20. / HEIGHT);

glTexCoord2f(0., 1.);
glVertex2f(100. / WIDTH, 100. / HEIGHT);

glTexCoord2f(1., 1.);
glVertex2f(20. / WIDTH, 100. / HEIGHT);
glEnd();
```

And, also, here's the whole code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <ft2build.h>
#include FT_FREETYPE_H
#include <freetype2/freetype/freetype.h>

const unsigned int WIDTH = 640;
const unsigned int HEIGHT= 480;

const char *vertex_shader_src =
"#version 330 core\n"
"layout (location = 0) in vec4 vertex;\n"
"out vec2 TexCoords;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"gl_Position = vec4(vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);\n"
"TexCoords = vertex.zw;}\0";

const char *frag_shader_src = 
"#version 330 core\n"
"in vec2 TexCoords;\n"
"out vec4 color;\n"
"uniform sampler2D text;\n"
"uniform vec4 textColor;\n"
"void main() {\n"
"vec4 sampled = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, texture(text, TexCoords).r);\n"
"color = textColor * sampled;}\0";

int main() {

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // WINDOW INITIALIZATION

    GLFWwindow *window;

    glfwInit();
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "SHADER", NULL, NULL);
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
    glfwSwapInterval(1);

    glClearColor(0., 0. , 0., 1.);
    glColor4f(1., 1., 1., 1.);
    glPointSize(1.);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, (WIDTH*1.)/HEIGHT, 1., 0, 1., -1.);
    glViewport(0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // SHADER INITIALIZATION

    glewInit();

    int vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(vertexShader, 1, &vertex_shader_src, NULL);
    glCompileShader(vertexShader);

    int fragShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
    glShaderSource(fragShader, 1, &frag_shader_src, NULL);
    glCompileShader(fragShader);

    int shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
    glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragShader);
    glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);

    glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
    glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // TEXTURE FOR A SINGLE CHARACTER
    FT_Library ft;
    if (FT_Init_FreeType(&ft)) {
        printf("Error in FT_Init_FreeType\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FT_Face face;
    if (FT_New_Face(ft, "Ubuntu-R.ttf", 0, &face)) {
        printf("Error in FT_New_Face\n");
        return 1;
    }

    FT_Set_Pixel_Sizes(face, 0, 96);
    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    if (FT_Load_Char(face, 'A', FT_LOAD_RENDER)) {
        printf("Error in FT_Load_Char\n");
        return 1;
    }

    unsigned int texID;
    glGenTextures(1, &texID);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);

    glTexImage2D(
        GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RED,
        face->glyph->bitmap.width,
        face->glyph->bitmap.rows,
        0, GL_RED, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,
        face->glyph->bitmap.buffer
    );

    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
    FT_Done_Face(face);
    FT_Done_FreeType(ft);

    // -------------------------------------------------------------------------
    // MAIN LOOP

    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window)) {

        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // Shader here
        glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
        glUniform4f(
            glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "textColor"),
            0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f
        );

        glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texID);
        glUniform1i(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "text"), 0);

        // Draw here
        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glTexCoord2f(1., 0.);
        glVertex2f(20. / WIDTH, 20. / HEIGHT);

        glTexCoord2f(0., 0.);
        glVertex2f(100. / WIDTH, 20. / HEIGHT);

        glTexCoord2f(0., 1.);
        glVertex2f(100. / WIDTH, 100. / HEIGHT);

        glTexCoord2f(1., 1.);
        glVertex2f(20. / WIDTH, 100. / HEIGHT);
        glEnd();
        glUseProgram(0);

        glFlush();
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);
        glfwPollEvents();

    }

    glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
    glfwDestroyWindow(window);
    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;

}
```

I suspect the problem is either because I'm not actually sending the texture to the shader or the shader is wrong.

Comment: Where are your `glVertexAttribPointer()` call(s)?  Because you aren't using the fixed-function compatibility attributes in your shaders.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't think I understood that last "fixed-function compatibility attributes" part. I'm not sure what that would be, if you care to explain.

Comment: How do you expect `glTexCoord2f` and `glVertex2f` to appear in the `vertex` attribute? These are legacy deprecated fixed-pipeline functions and you should use `glVertexAttribPointer` and `glDrawArrays` instead.

Comment: See section 7.2 "Compatibility Profile Vertex Shader Built-In Inputs" (page 151) in the [OpenGL Shading Language 4.60 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.4.60.pdf) for the list of fixed-function vertex attribute variables like `gl_MultiTexCoord0`.

Comment: I had no idea those functions were deprecated! Thank you both very much for your time!

Comment: Do you see how you are using the zw part of the vertex position for the texture coordinate, but your vertices don't have a zw part? Also, how should OpenGL know that `vertex` is meant to be the vertex position, anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [Legacy OpenGL](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Legacy_OpenGL) OpenGL and you are drawing the geometry by immediate mode [`glBegin`/`glEnd`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glBegin.xml) sequences. You cannot access the texture coordinates which are set by [`glTexCoord`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl2.1/xhtml/glTexCoord.xml) by a general vertex shader input. See [What are the Attribute locations for fixed function pipeline in OpenGL 4.0++ core profile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573235/what-are-the-attribute-locations-for-fixed-function-pipeline-in-opengl-4-0-cor).
You must downgrade the vertex shader to GLSL version 1.20 ([OpenGL Shading Language 1.20 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.20.pdf)) and you have to access the vertex coordinates by `gl_Vertex` and the texture coordinates by `gl_MultiTexCoord0`:

```c
#version 120

varying vec2 TexCoords;

void main() 
{
    gl_Position = vec4(gl_Vertex.xy, 0.0, 1.0);
    TexCoords = gl_MultiTexCoord0.st;
}
```

---

If you want to use the shader from the question, then you have to specify the arrays of vertex attributes by [`glVertexAttribPointer`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glVertexAttribPointer.xhtml) (see [Vertex Specification](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Vertex_Specification)) and you have to draw the geometry by [`glDrawArrays`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glDrawArrays.xhtml):

For instance:

```cpp
float vertex_attributes[] = {
     20. / WIDTH,  20. / HEIGHT, 1., 0.,
    100. / WIDTH,  20. / HEIGHT, 0., 0.,
    100. / WIDTH, 100. / HEIGHT, 0., 1.,
     20. / WIDTH, 100. / HEIGHT, 1., 1.
};

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, &vertex_attributes);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);
glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);
```

---

Please note, that `glewInit()` has to be done after `glfwMakeContextCurrent()` but before any OpenGL instruction.