# OpenGL - Can I take a look at default Shaders? (If there are any)

Tags: c++, opengl, driver

Using:

- OpenGl4
- Running on NVIDIA Graphics (I'm looking for a general approach / explanation, if there is any.)

After defining my vertex attribute data, without passing any shaders, I am able to see a triangle when running my Program.

```
DK_Vector2 positions[3] =
{
    DK_Vector2 { -0.5f, -0.5f },
    DK_Vector2 { 0.0f, 0.5f },
    DK_Vector2 { 0.5f, -0.5f },
};

unsigned int buffer;

glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(DK_Vector2), DK_Vector2::offsetX());
```

This must be any kind of default behavior of the graphics driver, musten't it?
Is there a way to look up which behavior the driver defaults to? Even when it's not understandable for a mere mortal?

Also, I have seen people online stating that there isn't such thing as a default shader. But again there must be?

I don't believe this should change anything, but I'm using

- GLFW (for creating a Window)
- GLEW (for managing OpenGL)

---

**Reproducible example** (but your outcome might differ (see question asked above)):
Application.cpp

```
#include <GL/glew.h>
#include <GLFW/glfw3.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "Vector2.h";

int main(void)
{
    GLFWwindow* window;

    /* Initialize the library */
    if (!glfwInit())
        return -1;

    /* Create a windowed mode window and its OpenGL context */
    window = glfwCreateWindow(640, 480, "Hello World", NULL, NULL);
    if (!window)
    {
        glfwTerminate();
        return -1;
    }

    /* Make the window's context current */
    glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);

    /* Initialize GLEW*/
    if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK)
        std::cout << "Main: GLEW Initialization failed!" << std::endl;

    std::cout << glGetString(GL_VERSION) << std::endl;

    DK_Vector2 positions[3] =
    {
        DK_Vector2 { -0.5f, -0.5f },
        DK_Vector2 { 0.0f, 0.5f },
        DK_Vector2 { 0.5f, -0.5f },
    };

    unsigned int buffer;
    glGenBuffers(1, &buffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 6 * sizeof(float), positions, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glVertexAttribPointer(0, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, sizeof(DK_Vector2), DK_Vector2::offsetX());


    /* Loop until the user closes the window */
    while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
    {
        /* Render here */
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);

        /* Swap front and back buffers */
        glfwSwapBuffers(window);

        /* Poll for and process events */
        glfwPollEvents();
    }

    glfwTerminate();
    return 0;
}
```

---

Vector2.cpp

```
#include "Vector2.h";

void* DK_Vector2::offsetX(){
    return (void*) &((DK_Vector2*)  nullptr)->x;
}

void* DK_Vector2::offsetY(){
    return (void*) &((DK_Vector2*)  nullptr)->y;
}
```

---

Vector2.h:

```
#pragma once
struct DK_Vector2
{
    float x, y;

    static void* offsetX();
    static void* offsetY();
};
```

Comment: No, that is not possible. There must be more at play here, which is not visible to us. Not only do you have no shader (program), you also have no vertex array object nor a drawing command. Could you present a reproducible example?

Comment: You might just want to use an Array of floats and 0 as offset. But I find it a little more readable while leaving Vector2 in the code.  Does this work for you? @ErdalKüçük

Comment: The answer will involve diving through your graphics driver implementation (mesa on Linux, closed source on Windows, MacOS) and figuring out how the OpenGL driver is implemented. I suggest you start sifting through the Zink source code, which implements OpenGL on top of Vulkan. You should be able to find "the default shader" very quickly.

Comment: But Zink being a Gallium driver is very specific to Vulcan, isn't it. Sounds like an edge case for devices that only support Vulkan. Or do you think Zink could be a representative Implementation of OpenGl inclusive "the default shader"? And for Windows NVIDIA drivers there is no way to find the source or the implementation "the default shader"? @Botje

Comment: The information you will get from Zink is about as broadly applicable as you would get for any other graphics driver. I would not depend on any specific detail beyond "it makes non-shader OpenGL commands work".

Comment: There is no such thing as a default shader. Since you are not requesting a core profile, my guess is that you are actually using the fixed-function pipeline. There is only a guarantee that attribute location 0 is the vertex position, but all other attributes are non-standard. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20573235/what-are-the-attribute-locations-for-fixed-function-pipeline-in-opengl-4-0-cor